# Referencing Calling Window From Module in VB.net WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a project with a bunch of windows.  I have another window where the user can choose the background for the windows.  I have a module that I would like to use to set the actual image.  That way, I don't need a whole bunch of code on every window...just one line.

```
modDothing.setthewallpaper(Me)
```

But this is not working.  It tells me in my module that the window is not defined.

I have commented out some of the things I have tried, but none of them work - or I wouldn't be here.  I am sure I am doing something dumb.  Is it the way I call the subroutine with (Me).  Thanks for any help on this

```vb
Module modDoThings

    Public Sub setthewallpaper(ByVal window3 As Window)
        'MsgBox(window3.GetType.Name)
        'Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of window3)().First().Close()

        Dim theWindow As Window = TryCast(window3, Window)

        Dim ih As New imageHolder
        Dim finalImage As Image = New Image()
        finalImage.Width = 380
        finalImage.Height = 300
        finalImage.Margin = New Thickness(5)
        Dim logo As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()
        logo.BeginInit()
        logo.UriSource = New Uri(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "images\myWalls\" & My.Settings.currentWall)
        logo.EndInit()
        ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(theWindow.WallBackground, logo)
        ImageBehavior.SetRepeatBehavior(theWindow.WallBackground, RepeatBehavior.Forever)
        theWindow.WallBackground.Source = logo

        'Dim targetWindow = TryCast(Application.Current.Windows.Cast(Of Window)().FirstOrDefault(Function(window) TypeOf window Is theWindow), theWindow)
        'targetWindow.WallBackground.Source = logo
        'Application.Current.Windows.OfType(Of window3)().First().WallBackground.Source = logo

    End Sub

End Module
```

Here is the image to show the squigglies.
[image: code squigglies]

Comment: Don't target some other window. Set a resource and your windows consume that as a dynamic resource. And don't try getting at application from some code library if that's what you're doing.

Comment: Also. Unless this logo is very fiddly I would be thinking in terms of vector. Geometry and or path instead of pictures.

Comment: You've shown us WHERE the errors are but not WHJAT they are. You need to provide the error messages. In this case though, the issue seems pretty obvious, and the error message would have told exactly what the issue is. Your `theWindow` variable is type `Window` and that type has no member named `WallBackground`.

Comment: BTW, even if it turns out to be wrong, you should only be writing code that makes logical sense. If a line of code can't do anything useful, why would you write it? In your case, your `window3` parameter is type `Window` and you try to cast it as type `Window`. What possible use could it be to cast something as the type it already is? Worse, you're using `TryCast` rather than `DirectCast` so you must think it might not be that type. How could a `Window` variable not refer to a `Window` object?

Comment: I don't get an error because it doesn't compile.  It only gives me the feedback that 'Window' is not defined.  Hence, I added the window3 cast to see if that would 'define' it.  I do get the TryCast vs DirectCast, but I just don't understand why it says it's not defined when the argument defines it as a window.  Very confusing for me.  I had just added a few things in there that I had tried to get it to work.

Comment: What is the exact compiler error?

Comment: Also, you may find things easier if you follow the WPF conventions of working through data binding instead of trying to directly manipulate forms.